# How can i add a click event to a circle layer in mapbox android?

Tags: android, kotlin, mapbox-android

I've created a circle layer in a mapbox. I can add an event to the annotations, but how can i add a event click in my circle layer and get the information from each particular point ?

I want to be able to click on the circle and then get the information in a popup. Is that possible ?

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        setContentView(binding.root)
        mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView)
        annotationAPI = mapView.annotations
        pointAnnotationManager = mapView.let { annotationAPI.createPointAnnotationManager(it) }

        observe()



        mapView.getMapboxMap().loadStyle(
            style (styleUri = Style.TRAFFIC_DAY) {
                +image("RESTROOMS") {
                    bitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.ic_red_marker))
                }
                +geoJsonSource(id = "source") {
                    url("asset://geo.json")
                    cluster(false)
                }
                +circleLayer("circle", "source") {
                    circleStrokeWidth(5.0)
                    circleColor(Color.WHITE)
                    circleStrokeColor(Color.RED)
                }

            },
            object : Style.OnStyleLoaded {
                override fun onStyleLoaded(style: Style) {
                    viewModel.getAssetList()
                }

            },
            object : OnMapLoadErrorListener {
                override fun onMapLoadError(eventData: MapLoadingErrorEventData) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "ERROR LOADING MAP")
                }
            }
        )
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        mapView?.onStart()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        mapView?.onStop()
    }

    override fun onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory()
        mapView?.onLowMemory()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        mapView?.onDestroy()
    }

   
}
```